How To Enable Livereload On VSCode
I have configured the settings in Visual Studio Code that are supposed to enable live reload in the console. But even though I have entered the code in the settings exactly as a YouTube video has mentioned, I am not getting the message on the console that says 'Live Reload is Enabled'.
This is the code the YouTuber had mentioned for the console to display the message and enable live reload:
{

  "liveServer.settings.useWebExt": false,

  "liveServer.settings.useLocalIp": true,

  code-runner.runInTerminal": true,

  "C_Cpp.updateChannel": "Insiders",

  "window.zoomLevel": 0,

  "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,

  "liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine": "",

  "C_Cpp.default.browse.path": [],

  "liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": "chrome"
}

